# How to renew yii RBAC assignments

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I'm working on a simple yii RBAC manager. All RBAC data is stored in database and everything works fine, but ...

When I decide to manage RBAC assignments I've got in trouble. For example, I assign operation "myNewOperation" to user "admin". Everything goes fine, accessControll and checkAccess() do their job. Then I decide to remove assignment record from database, but accessControll and checkAccess() still displays, that user have such rights. I tried to logout, clear cache, destroy session and clear cookies, but nothing changed. User "admin" still have rights "myNewOperation", but "myNewOperation" was physically removed from assignments table. What can be wrong?

Comment: may be he has some other rights that include this rights?

Comment: No, I clear the whole assignments table, but this magic is still happening

Comment: show accessControll and checkAccess

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I found the reason. It takes me to rummage in CDbAuthManager to understand it.
I did a logical mistake in my roles relations. I used default role "authenticated" so all authenticated users automaticly have that role. And I create a children operation from this role. By yii logic, if the is no access found, search will be continued on the parent branch. So I removed assignments, but had "authenticated" as parent, thats why I always had the "true" value. Thank you.